# Get vs grow (in the meaning become)

Tags: meaning

Is there any difference between these sentences:

> He got older.
>    He grew older.

And in general, what is the difference between *get*, *grow* and *become* in this context?

Comment: There are only shades of difference. 'He got older' is rather abrupt, corresponding to '20 years later' in a film. 'He grew older' connotes a more gradual overview of the process; think of it as corresponding to a few sequenced scenes, showing 'him' after 3, 6, 10, 13, 16, 20 years. 'He became older' isn't very idiomatic.

Comment: "Got" is also less formal.  If I found myself writing that in a formal paper, I'd change it to "became" or some more formal word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While ***grow*** and ***become*** both allude to "time" and/or "process" involved, ***"got"*** is more like a final assessment. Ex:

"During his period of obsession with video games, Bob **grew/became** soft and lazy."

"Wow... Bob sure **got** fat." (US)

Answer (score 1):

"Got" in this context is so informal, it borders on slang or dialect. "He grew older," might be the best option. Using "got" in this context makes the writer look careless or uninformed about proper--or at least elegant--word use.